# Ruby - help combining syntax for finding prime and reducing to the smallest divisor greater than 1 for non-prime numbers

Tags: ruby

I am completely and utterly brand new to this and trying to teach myself Ruby. I have been given a question to see if I can piece together what to do and prove problem solving skills via research and sheer determination so, keep in mind, I know very little about Ruby, I have been learning it for all of a day.

I need to first determine if an integer is a prime number (without using the required 'prime' directory, as far as I know) and then, if the result is true, my output needs to be 1. If it is false, my output needs to be the smallest divisor greater than one.

Piecing together things I found here and various other sites around the internet, I put together something I hoped would work. It does not.

```
def isPrime(n)
  ( 2..Math.sqrt(n)).each { |i|
    if n % i == 0 && i < n
    else
      n.reduce { |smallest, current| break if n <= 2 }
      puts n
    end
  }
1
```

I haven't the foggiest idea why it doesn't work. I know little about Ruby's syntax and I am reasonably certain that is where I am messing up.

Finding the prime number DOES work; it's the rest (finding the smallest divisor) that does not. And I'm sure my replacing true with 1 is mangling this horribly. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated. I have zero background in coding (unless you count my mom working in COBOL in the 80s) so, by all means, explain it like you would to a simpleton because I am THAT new.

Comment: Yes, your code is all kinds of broken. I'm not even sure it can be salvaged.

Comment: This deadline that you have, I hope it does allow you to do an introductory course on programming. Because even if we manage to write this one for you, you will not get too far without fundamentals.

Comment: "learn to program" by Chris Pine is a great book. Uses ruby for its code snippets. Check it out.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you, I will. I'm currently using some online tutorials and other sites to learn what I can. I've only just started.

Comment: I've tried to indent this code better, but it's still really confused. Can you try and clean it up a bit more? Your use of trailing `if` conditions, multi-line blocks without `do` ... `end` is making it hard to read. `reduce` is an array method, and `n` appears to be...an integer value?

Comment: @tadman thank you for your efforts! I'm still learning. I'm reading/working through the book that was suggested in an earlier comment and working on things. I think I need to just start over and try this again when I have learned a few more things. I already know so much more than I did when I started this just from reading the book.

Comment: Absolutely nothing wrong with learning. All I'm suggesting is when posting code that has problems do your best to get it into a form that executes even if it produces unexpected results. There's a ton of Ruby learning resources out there, so I hope you've found something that fits your style and needs.